# React Router cannot GET /route only after deployed to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, firebase, heroku, react-router, firebase-authentication

I have a simple web-app made with create-react-app and express.

All of the pages made with react router work fine locally, as well as online *on my own machine* once deployed to Heroku.

But, after testing online on other machines, I can't access these pages - whenever I click the links to them it displays `Cannot GET /*route*`

I still have the *name*.herokuapp.com domain if that affects it in any way

The redirect code I use is as follows: (I use firebase and react-bootstrap as well)

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <MyNavbar/>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/eateries" component={Eateries}/>
                <Route exact path="/thank-you" component={ThankYou}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Redirecting to /thank-you:

```
componentWillMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            window.location = "thank-you"
        } 
    })
}
```

So essentially when a user signs in through a modal component it should take them to /thank-you

Redirecting to /eateries:

```
<NavItem href="/eateries">
   For Eateries 
</NavItem>
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm redirecting users or using react router in general?

Comment: hard to tell without more information, but `window.location` should link to `/thank-you`

Comment: What inforrmation do you need?

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to know without seeing your server code - but in order to support `react-router`'s rendering mechanism, you need to use a wild card route in your server code:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve('build', 'index.html'));
```

This basically means "for any route not already matched, send the `index.html` file", which will then load your webapp, which in turn will handle routing. Note that you need to add the static middleware serving your assets before this - that's a gotcha I've forgotten many times. Most of your server file would then look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve('build', 'index.html'));

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log('listening for connections'));
```

Now, this would seem to work either way locally, since your web app is already loaded, and handles routing for you.

However, I've noticed that you're using `window.location` when redirecting your user. This makes some browsers at least (probably all) request the new page from the server, instead of letting the app deal with it. Instead, use the provided `history` property, which contains a `push` method.

```
componentWillMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.props.history.push('/thank-you');
    }
  });
}
```

This adds a new entry to the history stack. If you want a regular redirect, you should use `.replace` instead.

Hope this helps!